# Qt with Lua | Where to place lua file(s)

Tags: c++, qt, lua, qt-creator

I've created a cpp file with the main method implementing calls to lua.
When compiling + executing the qt project I receive the following error:

> PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a string value)

The problem is that lua cannot find the lua file to be executed (at least I think it is). So I copied the file to all the debug dirs and the main dir but it still didn't work.

Thanks for helping me!

---

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
    #include "lua.h"
    #include "lualib.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"
}

lua_State* L;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    /* initialize Lua */
    L = luaL_newstate();

    /* load Lua base libraries */
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    /* load the script */
    luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua");

    lua_call(L, 0, 0);

    /* cleanup Lua */
    lua_close(L);

}
```

and the file test.lua

```lua
-- test

print("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Qt uses the user's directory as default path.

You can validate this with: (thanks [Rich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667309/qt-with-lua-where-to-place-lua-files/41667390#comment70533633_41667643))

```
QDir dir(".");
qDebug() << dir.absolutePath();
```

When putting the lua script into this folder everything works like a charm.

The working directory can be set with the following command:

```
QDir::setCurrent()
```

And in combination with

```
QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()
```

The path can be set to where the exe resigns in.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is a run-time file operation, the function is likely only looking in the current directory.

Comment: I know where my compiled debug application runs from and added the Lua file there too but unfortunately it didn't work. I've also tried adding it in the parent dir of that directory but this didn't work either.

Comment: Put the file where you are launching the application from.

Comment: Are you certain you know where it's being executed from?  Sounds like you are using an IDE?

Comment: getcwd() will tell you where you really are.

Comment: I used QDir dir("."); with 
qDebug() << dir.absolutePath(); to find the path and it's the users directory. Placed the file there and it works now. Thanks for the pointer even though it wasn't exactly the current dir!

Answer (score 0):

This is not really related to Qt since you are not using any of the Qt API in your software.

You should check the status returned by the `lual_loadfile` method like shown in [this example](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleLuaApiExample). That should give you some additional clues about what is going wrong.

Just in case, there's a [QtLua module](http://www.nongnu.org/libqtlua/) that could be of interest.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer!
The problem is, that the message lua gives me is just that it cannot find the file and not where it is looking for it:
Couldn't load file: cannot open test.lua: No such file or directory
and if i change the -1 to -2 its just
Couldn't load file: (null)

QtLua looks promising but I would prefer the 'manual' way.

Comment: What OS are you on ?

Comment: Currently on Win10 (64 bit)

Comment: Use ProcMon from sysinternals to see where the program is looking